# jQueryUI .dialog("close") errors out on Chrome (ver50 to ver61-beta)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-ui, firefox

Save the following snippet as foo.html and open it using chrome and firefox, then press the "Test" button (this causes the entire document to be re-written from scratch) and finally press the "bar" button on the dialog that will pop up.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script> <!-- util service -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/1.2.1/jquery-migrate.js"></script> <!-- util service -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> <!-- util service -->
        <!-- util service -->
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dsidirop/082a2c1f9d23c1a8bcf86566289bdce9/raw/76367e47ee2ec82739a183e56f020c112dba16db/dummyUtilService.js"></script>
        <script>

                    document.open("text/html", "replace");
                    document.write("" +
                        "<!doctype html>" +
                        "<html>" +
                        "<head>" +
                        '   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">' +
                        "</head>" +
                        "<body>" +
                        '   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"><' + '/script>' +
                        '   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/1.2.1/jquery-migrate.js"><' + '/script>' +
                        '   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"><' + '/script>' +
                        '   <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dsidirop/082a2c1f9d23c1a8bcf86566289bdce9/raw/76367e47ee2ec82739a183e56f020c112dba16db/dummyUtilService.js"><' + '/script>' +                   
                        "   <script>" +
                        "       UtilService.foo({" +
                        "         buttons: [" +
                        "            {" +
                        '               text: "bar",' +
                        '               click: function () {' +
                        '                  console.log($(this).data("ui-dialog"));' +
                        '                  $(this).dialog("close");' +
                        '               }' +
                        '            }' +
                        '         ]' +
                        '       });' +
                        "   <" + "/script>" +
                        "<body>" +
                        "</html>"
                    );
                    document.close();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The snippet above employs a small utilities service called 'dummyUtilService.js'. The service is pretty trivial:

```
if (!window.UtilService)
{
    (function (self, $, undefined) {
        "use strict";

        self.foo = function (config) {
            return $("<div>").dialog(config);
        };
    }(window.UtilService = window.UtilService || {}, jQuery));
}
```

As long as the 'if (!window.UtilService)' bit is around the issue at hand occurs under chrome/firefox upon pressing the "bar" button:

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'
at Function.error (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js:253:9)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js:246:16)
at Function.each (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js:370:19)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js:137:17)
at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.(anonymous function) [as dialog] (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js:236:10)
at HTMLDivElement.click (file:///C:/Users/sido6001/Desktop/foo.html:42:578)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js:12443:12)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js:5226:27)
at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js:4878:28)
```

If we comment out 'if (!window.UtilService)' then everything works just fine under chrome. <s>Firefox doesn't care either way - everything works just fine under firefox regardless of whether 'if (!window.UtilService)' is commented out or not.</s>

Why does '$(this).data("ui-dialog")' return 'undefined' thus causing .dialog("close") to crash later on? [*]

[*] As far as my analysis went .dialog("close") crashes because an internal call to '$(this).data("ui-dialog")' returns undefined.

**Update**: I noticed that if the original code gets tweaked to include a button which triggers the document-replacement process then the mechanism starts working fine under firefox but it keeps on crashing in chrome. I have the hair at the back of my neck standing up right now given how subtle this change is and yet it triggers a different reaction in two main-stream browsers :S

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>Test</button>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script> <!-- util service -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/1.2.1/jquery-migrate.js"></script> <!-- util service -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> <!-- util service -->
        <!-- util service -->
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dsidirop/082a2c1f9d23c1a8bcf86566289bdce9/raw/76367e47ee2ec82739a183e56f020c112dba16db/dummyUtilService.js"></script>
        <script>
                $("button").on("click", function() {
                    document.open("text/html", "replace");
                    document.write("" +
                        "<!doctype html>" +
                        "<html>" +
                        "<head>" +
                        '   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">' +
                        "</head>" +
                        "<body>" +
                        '   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"><' + '/script>' +
                        '   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/1.2.1/jquery-migrate.js"><' + '/script>' +
                        '   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"><' + '/script>' +
                        '   <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dsidirop/082a2c1f9d23c1a8bcf86566289bdce9/raw/76367e47ee2ec82739a183e56f020c112dba16db/dummyUtilService.js"><' + '/script>' +                   
                        "   <script>" +
                        "       UtilService.foo({" +
                        "         buttons: [" +
                        "            {" +
                        '               text: "bar",' +
                        '               click: function () {' +
                        '                  console.log($(this).data("ui-dialog"));' +
                        '                  $(this).dialog("close");' +
                        '               }' +
                        '            }' +
                        '         ]' +
                        '       });' +
                        "   <" + "/script>" +
                        "<body>" +
                        "</html>"
                    );
                    document.close();
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see `$(this).dialog("close");` yet I do not see where `.dialog()` is defined on any element. The error is simply saying you cannot close a dialog object that has not been created.

Comment: Ok, I see what's being attempted. May want to add some logging in `foo` to ensure it's executing properly. May also want to add `id` to your `<div>` element and call that versus a potentially ambiguous `$(this)`

Comment: If you read through the post one more time you will notice that this mechanism works just fine under firefox. I've tested this technique time and over again under chrome (without over-writing the document like I do here) and it works just fine. For some reason this issue crops up under chrome after over-writing the entire document with a fresh block of html. Qurious.

Comment: I have read over this post a few times. I understand that it works in FF and not Chrome. There are a number of things that are not clear about this. One, I did not understand the reason for wanting to rewrite your document. I suspect there is a subtle difference in how the DOM elements are created / loaded in doing this. I do most my work in FF, and have Lubuntu with Chromium, so I have a poor test environment to replicate the issue in.

Comment: We have a generic loading dialog which gets filled asynchronously while loading for a huge page to get rendered. Once the page is complete we receive the html and replace the entire page with it as demonstrated here. In the resulting page the dialogs don't work as intended under chrome. That's how we noticed this issue to begin with. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, will see if I can test it locally as you advised and see what I can dig out.